# Why does the model not pass back to the controller on post?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

My model is not passing back to the controller on post.  I'm doing this in another part of the application and it works fine.  I have probably missed something but I have been over this for two days and I can't see it.  I hope you can assist.

My View:

```
@model Towins.Models.T_Complaints
@{
  ViewBag.Title = "UpsertComplaint";
  Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

@using (Html.BeginForm("UpsertComplaint_Post", "Home", FormMethod.Post))
{
@Html.AntiForgeryToken()

// The model is working on the get. 
// The date has been supplied in the get and I have it in the view. 
// The Model.Id == 0 as this is the add portion of the upsert. 
// Can't even start working on the update portion as the model is not coming back at all.

<h4>@(Model.Id!=0 ? "Edit" : "Add") Complaint</h4>
<hr />
@Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Id)
@Html.HiddenFor(model => model.WreckerID)
<div class="container text" style="text-align: center">
    <div class="form-row">
        <div class="form-group col-6">
            <label for="NewWrecker" class="col-form-label">Wrecker Company Name</label>
            <input type="text" disabled class="form-control" id="WreckerCo" name="WreckerCo" value="@ViewBag.WreckerCo" />
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-row">
        <div id="DateOfComplaint-group" class="input-group date form-group col-6" data-date-format="dd/mm/yyyy">
            <label for="ComplaintDate" class="col-form-label">Complaint Date:&nbsp;</label>
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.ComplaintDate, "{0:mm/dd/yyyy}", new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></i></span>
        </div>
    </div>

    // Model Fields deleted for brevity

    <div class="form-group row col-6">
            <div class="col-12 row">
                <div class="col-6">
                    <input type="submit" name="NewComplaint" class="btn btn-primary" value="Save" />
                </div>
                <div class="col-6">
                    <a href="@Url.Action("ComplaintList", new { wId = ViewBag.WreckerId })" class="btn btn-primary">Back to Complaints List</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
</div>
```

}

My Controller: This is posting properly but the model is null

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult UpsertComplaint_Post(T_Complaints complaint)

    {

    // complaint is null here.
    // This is as far as I have gotten. I can't copmplete the post code until I
    // can get the model back to this point.

        return RedirectToAction("ComplaintList", new RouteValueDictionary(new { wId = complaint.WreckerID }));
    }
```

And just for completeness, here is the model:

```
    public class T_Complaints
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [DataType(DataType.MultilineText)]
    public string Complaint { get; set; }
    [DataType(DataType.MultilineText)]
    [Display(Name = "Complainant Info")]
    public string ComplainantInfo { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public int WreckerID { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public bool Resolved { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [DataType(DataType.Date)]
    [Display(Name = "Complainant Date")]
    public DateTime ComplaintDate { get; set; }
    [DataType(DataType.Date)]
    [Display(Name = "Resolution Date")]
    public DateTime ResolutionDate { get; set; }
    [DataType(DataType.MultilineText)]
    public string Resolution { get; set; }
}
```

Here is the Get Action

```
       [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult UpsertComplaint(int? cid, string WreckerCo, int wId)
    {
        T_Complaints complaint = new T_Complaints();
        ViewBag.WreckerCo = WreckerCo;
        ViewBag.wId = wId;
        if (cid == null)

        // This is true so this is the block that executes on Add

        {
            complaint.ComplaintDate = DateTime.Now;
            complaint.WreckerID = wId;
            return View(complaint);
        }
        using (con)
        {
            con.Open();
            using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM [Towins].[dbo].[T_Complaints] WHERE Id = " + cid, con))
            {
                SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                if (reader.HasRows)
                {
                    while (reader.Read())
                    {
                        complaint.Resolved = (bool)reader["Resolved"];
                        complaint.Id = (int)reader["Id"];
                        complaint.Complaint = reader["Complaint"].ToString();
                        ViewBag.WreckerId = reader["WreckerID"];
                        complaint.ComplainantInfo = reader["ComplainantInfo"].ToString();
                        complaint.ComplaintDate = (DateTime)reader["ComplaintDate"];
                        if (reader["ResolutionDate"].ToString() != "")
                        {
                            complaint.ResolutionDate = (DateTime)reader["ResolutionDate"];
                        }
                        complaint.Resolution = reader["Resolution"].ToString();
                    };
                }
                reader.Close();
            }
            con.Close();
        }
        return View(complaint);
    }
```

Okay. I've gotten some downgrades for insufficient research and not posting the question properly.  I'm going to reattempt to get this question answered.  I have simplified everything with test code and reposted it here:

My new test model in it's entirety:

```
namespace Towins.Models
{
    public class T_ComplaintsTest
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Complaint { get; set; }
    }
}
```

My new test View in its entirety:

```
@model Towins.Models.T_ComplaintsTest

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "AddComplaint";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

<h2>Add Complaint</h2>


@using (Html.BeginForm("AddComplaint", "Home", FormMethod.Post))
{
    <div class="text" style="text-align: center">
        <div class="form-row">
            <div class="form-group col-6">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Complaint)
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Complaint, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group row col-6">
            <div class="col-12 row">
                <div class="col-6">
                    <input type="submit" name="AddComplaint" class="btn btn-primary" value="Save" />
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
}
```

And, my action methods in their entirety:

```
    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult AddComplaint()
    {
        T_ComplaintsTest complaint = new T_ComplaintsTest();
        complaint.Complaint = "Test";
        return View(complaint);
    }
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult AddComplaint(T_ComplaintsTest complaint)

    {
        //Breakpoint here.  Why is complaint null?
        return RedirectToAction("ComplaintList", new RouteValueDictionary(new { wId = 247 }));
    }
```

When the Get occurs, it successfully renders "Test" in the field. When I hit the submit button, it stops at the breakpoint "return RedirectToAction..."  Why at this point is complaint null? I can see no reason for the life of me why it should be null.  The view is of this Model.  Should it not be there?

Comment: Can you post a  controller and get action that you use to  show a view, pls?

Comment: I added the get action.

Comment: I see you have only one input control ComplaintDate . DateTime is usually tricky to post. Did you try to post not new but updated item that has all fields data?

Comment: @SteveCross You are posting to your `Controller` method without the `[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]` attribute. You are generating a `@Html.AntiForgeryToken()` on your `View`. I am surprised that you are not getting an error on the submit.

Comment: Are are you positive `UpsertComplaint_Post` is getting hit at all?

Comment: Yes.  It is definitely executing.  It stops at the breakpoint in the controller.  This is how I'm able to confirm that the model is null.

Comment: @Serge It is correctly returning the ComplaintDate on the get but the entire model is null on the post.  I have changed fields as this is supposed to ultimately be an insert.;

Comment: @RahulSharma, I attempted to add the [ValidateAntiForgeryToken] to the controller and got an error so I removed the @Html.AntiForgeryToken() from the view and still, the model is null on post.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer is simply that the model binder is getting confused.

Inside your `T_Complaints` class, you have a property called `Complaint`.
In your post action, you used complaint as the model name:

```
public ActionResult AddComplaint(T_ComplaintsTest complaint)
```

Simply changing the model name in the controller will make things less complicated for the model binder and your model won't be null.

```
public ActionResult AddComplaint(T_ComplaintsTest complaintsTest) // this won't be null anymore.
```

Comment: Wow.  I knew it had to be something simple.  Thank you so much.  That was exactly the problem.